# spring-boot create non-embedded datasource in non-web application

Tags: grails, grails-orm, spring-boot

I am trying to use Grails GORM from a spring-boot application and have a set of tests which run with the embedded database. I cannot, however, move the code to a different database server (which is required for some of the tests.)

Following the Spring Guide at (http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-gorm/) I have the following in src/main/resources/application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.intialize=false
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.2/mydb? useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
```

I have the following for gradle dependencies, including the item for Grails GORM:

```
dependencies {
  compile(
     "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4jVersion",
     "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web",
     "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jpa",
     "org.grails:gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot:1.0.0.RELEASE",
     "com.h2database:h2:$h2Version",
     "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:8.0.8"
  )

  runtime(
     "ch.qos.logback:logback-access:1.1.2",
     "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2",
     "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.30")

  testCompile(
     "junit:junit",
     'org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0' )
}
```

Running a test and the log contains `Creating embedded database 'testdb'`. This remains the case whether I change the properties to contain `spring.datasource.intialize=true` or change the dependency to `spring-boot-starter-web` (or both).

The documentation for Spring Boot seems to imply that adding the properties to application.properties should activate the other database. The answer at [Spring boot did not create datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253483/spring-boot-did-not-create-datasource) seemed to imply that ensuring that tomcat and the driver are on the classpath should fix the problem, but I've check the path and with the `spring-boot-starter-web` and the above dependency, both are on the classpath so that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

The auto configuration report (somewhat long) is below. It seems to report that the class org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource is not found. Yet it is shown on the classpath in my IDE and should be there per the dependency.

```
=========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   MessageSourceAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.MessageSource; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedConfiguration
      - embedded database H2 detected (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedDatabaseCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.JdbcTemplateConfiguration
      - existing auto database detected (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.DatabaseCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.JdbcTemplateConfiguration#jdbcTemplate
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.JdbcTemplateConfiguration#namedParameterJdbcTemplate
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate,org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.TransactionManagementConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JmxAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter (OnClassCondition)
      - SpEL expression on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration: ${spring.jmx.enabled:true} (OnExpressionCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   RabbitAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate,com.rabbitmq.client.Channel (OnClassCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect,org.aspectj.lang.reflect.Advice (OnClassCondition)

   BatchAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher (OnClassCondition)

   JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository (OnClassCondition)

   MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: com.mongodb.Mongo,org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.DbcpConfiguration
      - org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource DataSource class not found (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.BasicDatabaseCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.TomcatConfiguration
      - org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource DataSource class not found (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.TomcatDatabaseCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration#transactionManager
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: transactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [transactionManager] (OnBeanCondition)

   JmsTemplateAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate,javax.jms.ConnectionFactory (OnClassCondition)

   DeviceResolverAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor,org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver (OnClassCondition)

   MongoAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: com.mongodb.Mongo (OnClassCondition)

   MongoTemplateAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: com.mongodb.Mongo,org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate (OnClassCondition)

   HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
      - did not find HibernateEntityManager class (HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.HibernateEntityManagerCondition)

   ReactorAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: reactor.spring.context.config.EnableReactor (OnClassCondition)

   RedisAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection,org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations,com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisClient (OnClassCondition)

   FallbackWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
      - SpEL expression on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.FallbackWebSecurityAutoConfiguration: !${security.basic.enabled:true} (OnExpressionCondition)

   SecurityAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager (OnClassCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine (OnClassCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration
      - web application classes not found (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration
      - web application classes not found (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter (OnClassCondition)

   MultipartAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver (OnClassCondition)

   ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration
      - web application classes not found (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration
      - web application classes not found (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   WebSocketAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat,org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler,org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci (OnClassCondition)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix turned out to be hard to find, but not difficult. The trick is to add a runtime dependency on the appropriate version of `org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:`. For Java 6, I used 7.0.54. For Java 7 or 8, use 8.0.8. Note that the 7. series is not listed as the latest on Maven Central.

Apparently this dependency is not pulled in by the web starter so has to be added.

The hard part in finding this was that if the class is not loadable for some reason, such as an incompatible JRE, it silently fails to find it. I only found this problem when trying to explicitly load the class.

Comment: tomcat-jdbc:7.0.54 would be added transitively by the JPA starter which you already have, so it's a mystery to me why you wouldn't get a `DataSource` created automatically. I think it should work with Java 6,7 or 8. You didn't actually say which you were using.